# What is the term for the last word of each line in rhyme/poem? The word that is actually the rhyming one

Tags: poetry, terminology

If we take this ABAB stanza, for example:

*The people along the* ***sand***
*All turn and look one* ***way***.
*They turn their back on the* ***land***.
*They look at the sea all* ***day***.

It's very easy to spot the words that rhyme (bolded), but is there a specific term for those words?

Comment: Words in rhyming position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual term is just **rhyme**! (In sense 1c.)

> **rhyme, *n.* 1.b.** Correspondence of sound between the endings of two or more words or metrical lines such that the syllables involved carry identical vowel sounds and have (if present) identical final consonants.
>
> **c.** An instance of such correspondence of sounds; a word so corresponding in sound with another.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

Where there may be confusion with the more abstract sense 1b, some authors use **rhyme word**:

> 1896   [*The Athenaeum* no. 3569 p. 372](https://archive.org/details/p1athenaeum1896lond/page/372/mode/2up)   The poet must know the instant that a **rhyme-word** presents itself to his mind what **rhyme-word** will do swift and concise work, and what **rhyme-word** will not.
>
> 1902   [Hartley Coleridge *Works of Lord Byron* vol. VI p. 278](https://archive.org/details/workslordbyron00ernlgoog/page/278/mode/2up) The repetition of the same **rhyme-word** was noted in *Blackwood’s Edinburgh Magazine*
>
> 1925   [Amy Lowell *John Keats* vol. II p. 204](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.234838/page/n221/mode/2up)   It may be objected that “moors” is also merely a **rhyme word**, but this I doubt, principally because it does not properly rhyme at all.

However, the part of the line that rhymes is sometimes shorter than a word:

> At mortal batailles hadde he been fiftene,
> And foughten for oure feith at Tramyssene
>
> <sub>Geoffrey Chaucer (c. 1400). [*General Prologue to the Canterbury Tales*, lines 61–62](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Canterbury_Tales_(unsourced)/General_Prologue). Wikisource.</sub>

and sometimes longer:

> There stands the Master. Study, my friends,
>     What a man’s work comes to! So he plans it,
> Performs it, perfects it, makes amends
>     For the toiling and moiling, and then, *sic transit!*
>
> <sub>Robert Browning (1855 rev. 1868). ‘[Old Pictures in Florence](https://archive.org/details/poeticalworksofr03browrich/page/134/mode/2up)’. In *The Poetical Works of Robert Browning*, volume III, p. 134. London: Smith, Elder.</sub>

Perhaps for this reason, the term **rhyming element** is sometimes used for the sound or group of sounds that correspond: “ene” in Chaucer and “ansit” in Browning.

> Normally the last stressed vowel in the line and all sounds following it make up the **rhyming element**.
>
> <sub>Chris Baldick (1990). [*The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Literary Terms*, p. 189](https://archive.org/details/conciseoxforddic0000bald_v3k9/page/188/mode/2up). Oxford University Press.</sub>